# Getting field value of a MongoDB document using another value of the same document (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Let's imagine I have an MongoDB document that includes the following data:

```
{
    "username": "test123",
    "password": "$2b$10$M2Y3ELsgfvA4KHxdCJkezeHZ1kKgtOA2Jiq4kuwqcRJSovGBu9nLm"
}
```

The password is hashed using `bcrypt`. Using MongoDB's official Node driver, I can find the username with:

```
collection.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
```

But how can I find the username, then check the `password` value of the same document (the password related to the username), and finally return the password?

PS. I know the title is very confusing, if you can think of a better way to express it, please comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bad practice to send encrypted passwords to the database. It has some security issues. I guess you want to get the user by its username, figure out if it's the right user that you fetched by comparing its password also (password hashes), then do something with that user - for example, return password or so, as you mentioned (I don't see why would you expose password back to anyone).
For encryption, I'm using `bcryptjs` [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs), but it's pretty similar. Its function `compare()` takes the raw password for the first argument, and takes hashed password from the database as the second argument. It hashes the raw password and compares it with the given hash. If hashes match, the password is valid. For a code, you would have something like:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

// ...
const user = await collection.findOne({ username: req.body.username });

if (!user) throw new Error('User doesn\'t exist');

// first argument "password" is a raw password to compare with the one in the document
const passwordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

if (!passwordValid) throw new Error('Invalid password');

// do whatever you want to do with validated user
// if you want password to return, raw "password" is the one that's in the database also (hash)
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer I was looking for. If I still may ask, why is it exactly a bad practice to send encrypted passwords to databases? And when should they be encrypted then?

Comment: Passwords should be hashed, not encrypted. Everything encrypted can be somehow decrypted, depending on the algorithm and so on. But, hashes are a "one-way street". When you hash something, you can validate that value only if the data that has to be compared is hashed also, then compared with the first hash. If someone steals your data from your database it's easier to that person to get to your original password, if it's encrypted. Imagine that password being used in multiple places.
Though I had to mention that as many programmers still find that confusing.
Did you get all your answers?

Comment: Oh well, it's my bad then, since I thought that encrypting and hashing are the same thing. I will edit the question to say ``hash`` instead of ``encrypt``, because hashing is what I meant here.

And yes, I got all the answers now. Thanks again!